# Total derivative of function on a curve

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Consider the function
$$F=F(x,y,z)$$ where $x,y,z$ describe the curve

$x=x(u)$,

$y=y(u)$,

$z=z(u)$

Since the total differential is

$$dF(x,y,z)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}dz$$

Is it correct to say that the total derivative of F w/respect to say, z is

$$\frac{dF(x,y,z)}{dz}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dz}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dz}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}$$

Is it correct to write the above total derivative as

$$\frac{dF(x,y,z)}{dz}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{(\frac{dx}{du})}{(\frac{dz}{du})}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{(\frac{dy}{du})}{(\frac{dz}{du})}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}$$

Assume $(\frac{dz}{du})$ is not zero and that $x,y,z$ are invertible functions of $u$, so one can express $u=u(x), u=u(y), u=u(z)$

As a side question, would it be sufficient to write $\frac{dx}{dz}=\frac{(\frac{dx}{du})}{(\frac{dz}{du})}$ without needing the invertibility?

Comment: The intuition seems right, but I'm a little uncertain: What happens if $z(u)$ is a constant?

Comment: I see your point, will make an edit

Comment: It's not clear that you can write $x$ and $y$ as functions of $z$ -- you know each depends on $u$, but for such a claim you'd need to know that that dependence is somehow invertible. What would make sense is something like $\frac{dF}{du}$.

Comment: True, I will add an edit about this